# Can a library(.jar) that is implemented in your project be able to access user data?

Tags: android, security

Say I have considered to use a library by adding in project's gradle:

```
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Can the code running in that jar file access the user details such as device id, location, files, etc.. if the user has granted those in my application?

I'm worried because I'm using some of those .jar libraries, but I cannot verify how trustworthy those are. I'm just worried about these libraries accessing such information and storing it on their servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you call into the library's code at any point (or even cause its classes to be loaded), it can execute code with the same permissions as if you had written the code yourself.

As for why this is, once the app is compiled, everything ends up (more or less) being combined into the same bytecode file(s).  This is usually desirable - apps probably want libraries to use their app's permissions most of the time.  But it does mean that there's no easy way to "sandbox" a library's code to prevent it from using permissions/accessing/transmitting data.

Comment: Can that also happen if a class in .jar file is calling native code elsewhere in a .so file?

Comment: Yes, any code you call within your app can do anything you can

Comment: But i know there are some modules that have a manifest file of their own. Will those libraries be able to execute code outside of permissions in their manifest?

Comment: Yes, they will be able to execute code with all your app's permissions. All the manifest files are also combined into one, so all code within your app has the same Android permissions.

Comment: Sure, I've upvoted it, Can you also provide a link to resource that explains how this works?

Comment: Sure: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you recommend reading the entire documentation before considering to become a serious developer?

Comment: Also, do you have good knowledge of the Gradle system and how it works, the way I was taught Android development didn't include any of the insights

Comment: I've been doing this a long time so I've encountered a lot, but there's still a lot of documentation I haven't read yet (and more being written every day).  Keep picking things up as you encounter them and you should be fine :-) Best of luck!